# CiviCRM for Outlook - Invalid Credentials

Tags: civimail, error

I set everything up for the civicrm for outlook extension according to these instructions http://www.vedaconsulting.co.uk/outlookforcivicrm-release. I am using the api extension to generate the api key. But i keep getting the "Invalid Credentials" error message in outlook when i try to connect it. Any thoughts on what could be causing this to not be able to connect?

Comment: +1. I get the same thing on 4.7.15. Have also checked AJAX permissions are enabled for my role, and API key set. [![outlook integration not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrk2L.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrk2L.png)
[![forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZWv9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZWv9.png)

Comment: I get the same issue. How did you solve this. @Rbo I can't access the url in a browser, I get an error 403, is this the mistake?

Comment: You've posted this as an answer but this doesn't appear to answer the question. You are more likely to get a response if you add a comment or post a new question (possibly referencing this question if relevant).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a civi expert by any means, but thought I would share my experience - I had a similar issue, and it turned out to be a firewall issue - civi was hosted on a machine on the net, and my Outlook client was on our corporate network. When I was connected to our company network, I would get that error. When I took the machine home and tried connecting there - it worked fine.

Other things that got me to start with - in the URL path, make sure you have the trailing / on the path   (check by copying the url and trying to access the url in a browser), and make sure you're using the correct site key from the civicrm.settings.php file

Hope something here helps!